# BITCOIN ADDRESS

Tags: blockchain

My 0.01673232 BTC SENT to the following Address automatically when last time I opened my Blockchain Wallet and now Balance shows 0.00

Sent to this Address: 3CKJ3Q49vfCB8MhhA9wtS1uXsBhoYHiAqh

Now my Question is that What should I do to recover my BTC.

Thanks

Muneer

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to recover my BTC.

nothing. but you should check your system for malware and clean it before using bitcoin again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recover your bitcoins once they have been stolen there is nothing you can do.